# Timing delay on my PIC

Tags: delay, timing, pic

Prepare for a nooby question.

I'm writing some ultra-simple code for this new PIC which I've just got. All I'm trying to do is to flash an LED. Below are two code samples - the first works but the second doesn't. Why?? I can't see any problem with the second one.

WORKS:

```
        while(1)
{
    i=99999;
    while(i--) {
        LATAbits.LATA0 = 0;  // set RA0 to logic 1
    }
    i=99999;
    while(i--) {
    LATAbits.LATA0 = 1;  // set RA0 to logic 0
    }
}
```

DOESN'T WORK:

```
        while(1)
{
    LATAbits.LATA0 = 1;  // set RA0 to logic 1
    for(i=0;i<99999;i++) {}
    LATAbits.LATA0 = 0;  // set RA0 to logic 0
    for(i=0;i<99999;i++) {}
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
while(1)
{
    for(i=0;i<99999;i++) 
    {
        LATAbits.LATA0 = 1;  // set RA0 to logic 1
    } 
    for(i=0;i<99999;i++) 
    {
        LATAbits.LATA0 = 0;  // set RA0 to logic 0
    }
}
```

Maybe your compiler is optimizing and ignoring the `for` statements as they have no code to execute inside. What I did was put the RA0 assignment inside these statements, forcing the compiler to keep the delay loops.

You can also pass the argument `-S` to your compiler to see the assembly code generated and confirm that the `for` statements were removed. The `-S` option generates an intermediate file with a *".S"* extension.

Comment: Yes thanks, that seems like the answer. So if I wanted some code that doesn't actually do anything, to execute in the 'for' loop, could I use something like asm("NOP")?

Comment: I always write code for PIC directly in assembly, so I can't confirm that; it makes sense though, so probably yes, it will work as you expect.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? You can probably use `__asm__("NOP");` but this doesn't work for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

1. What's your definition of `i`? `char i`? `int i`? `long i`?
2. What PIC are you using?

If you're using an `int`, the 8-bit PICs use a 16-bit `int`.

So what happens:

```
// Try to stuff 99999 into 16-bits, but it becomes 34463
i=99999;

// Count-down from 34463 to zero
while(i--) {}

// Successfully exit delay
```

As opposed to:

```
// Count up from zero
// Get to 65535 and then reset to zero
// Never reach 99999
for(i=0;i<99999;i++) {}
// Never exit delay
```

Try using `unsigned long int` for i, which tends to be 32-bit on PICs and see if it starts to work.